# How do I make a write operation in Realm (iOS) synchronous?

Tags: ios, realm

As part of an two step analysis process, I need data to be written to the persistent storage prior to the second step beginning. If I do this asynchronously via fina grain notifications its a bit messy. It would be great two do it in-line in one function.

Is it possible to make a Realm().write { } opperations synchronous? The second step will need to read this data back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Realm.write(_:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm5writeFzFT_T_T_) *is* synchronous.

Comment: That was easy. I just assumed that because it was a block that its not. Thx.

Comment: One way to tell it's synchronous from the documentation is the `@noescape` attribute. A closure parameter with that attribute must be used within the function, and cannot escape the lifetime of the call itself. See [Nonescaping Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID546) in the Swift documentation for more information.

Comment: It is *not* synchronous. Effectively, at least. If you write a value, then query for that object from another thread using realm.objects(), the value will not always be updated.

Comment: Whether or not the method is synchronous is orthogonal to when the results are visible to other threads. Changes are visible to other threads only after their Realm refreshes to see a newer version of the data (on the next runloop iteration on the main thread, or due to an explicit call to `refresh()` on a background thread).

Comment: @tempire you're right, some time refresh() itself won't help. Even if we updated a value on a line of code,  it may not get updated when trying to access it from the next line after refresh().