# React Native Realm database: How to return a promise from a write command?

Tags: react-native, promise, realm

I am using Realm.io database in a React Native app. I have a simple write command:

```
    Realm.write(() => {
        Realm.create('Dog', { name: 'Bob'}, true);
    });  

    //Few lines below, make a query for the Bob the dog.
```

If the write operation for some reason takes more then couple of milliseconds, how can I make sure that when I query for Bob the dog, I will get the updated object?

Is there a way for the write operation to return a promise or something simillar so I can be sure to execute code only after the write operation succeeded?

Comment: It feels like it does the operations instantly and sequentially. I am not sure though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Realm *is* synchronous. [All callbacks handed to #write are blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38082770/how-do-i-make-a-write-operation-in-realm-ios-synchronous), but that's not such a big deal as it is optimized for React Native. Still, [the docs say](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#writes)

> Write transactions incur non-negligible overhead - you should architect your code to minimize the number of write transactions.

Comment: What would be a transaction in this case? If I call three `create` inside a `write`, would it mean three transactions (three creations), or only one (one write)?

Comment: I believe that's only counted as one.

Comment: Even though the topic is pretty old I'd like to add to @Fermuch I'd say each `write` counts as a transaction, not the `creates`, so the `write` lets you group transactions, that's my understanding